# Bootstrap header/jumbotron background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm messing around with Bootstrap for the first time and was struggling to get an image as the background for a header that included the nav and jumbotron. Currently the image I've set isn't showing up and I'm not sure why.  If you could point me in the right direction as to where or what needs to change it would be appreciated.

[image]

```
<div class="container header-bg">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Elliott Davidson</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Pictures</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Videos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Sponsors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Elliott Davidson</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

    .header-bg {
      width:100%;
      height:475px;
      background: url("img/elliott-davidson-slider.jpg");
      background-size:cover;
    }

    .jumbotron {
      color: white;
      text-shadow: black 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
      background: transparent;
    }
```

Comment: And what is your current problem? You said what you wanted, but it would help if you say what you are getting right now

Comment: The image isn't displaying sorry will update post

Comment: a screenshot would be nice too

Comment: what is your directory structure? Are you getting any errors in a web inspector like a 404 not found?

Comment: just root directory with img folder in it for images. Console says "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: file:///Users/user/Sites/elliott-davidson/index.html

Comment: And your `img` folder is in the same directory that your **css file**? Because generally, and according to Bootstrap structure, they are not, in that case your background url should be `background: url("../img/elliott-davidson-slider.jpg");`

Comment: That worked thanks. How do I align the image in the center instead of left. I tried margin right/left auto and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background: url("../img/elliott-davidson-slider.jpg");
```

By –  Yerko Palma

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "background-image" like so:

```
.header-bg {
  width:100%;
  height:475px;
  background-image: url("img/elliott-davidson-slider.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
```